# How can I install GNOME 3 on CentOS 6.3?

Tags: linux, gnome, centos, gnome3, centos-6

Would be possible to install GNOME 3 (instead of 2.28 that ships with CentOS) on a minimal CentOS 6.3 install? Is there any repository that provides packages for the new version?

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from the [Gnome website](http://www.gnome.org/getting-gnome/)

Haven't tried this yet, although I will do so in the next couple of days. If you get it working, could you say how and I'll do the same.