# CentOS 6.3 and GNOME 3 (gnome-shell) installation from repository

Tags: linux, centos, gnome

Is there any possibility to install GNOME 3 (gnome-shell) from repository on CentOS 6.3, e.g. does some extra repository with GNOME 3 exist?

I've read [the thread about installing GNOME 3 on CentOS 6.3](https://superuser.com/questions/467105/how-can-i-install-gnome-3-on-centos-6-3) already but it's quite old, so I think that some better solution may exists (I don't think that's optimal to install GUI without repository).

And nope, I can't use CentOS 7 or another distro on this machine (it's not my choice, it's a rule).